# Check for null before continuing LINQ and return value as "-"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this code.

```cs
DisplayTimeStamp = PredictionTableList
    .Where(x => x.ContextTimestamp != null)
    .Select(x => x.ContextTimestamp)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

It returns the first data of the table.
Sometimes `PredictionTableList` is null, how do I check for this and return the null value as "-"?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used some of your solutions and I used this if

 (PredictionTableList != null && PredictionTableList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    DisplayTimeStamp = PredictionTableList
                       .Select(x => x.ContextTimestamp)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
                }
                else
                   DisplayTimeStamp = null;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**: An `if-else` statement to check whether `PredictionTableList` is `null`.

```cs
if (PredictionTableList == null)
    DisplayTimeStamp = "-";
else
    DisplayTimeStamp = PredictionTableList.Where(x => x.ContextTimestamp != null)
        .Select(x => x.ContextTimestamp)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Option 2**: Ternary operator

```cs
DisplayTimeStamp = PredictionTableList == null
    ? "-"
    : PredictionTableList.Where(x => x.ContextTimestamp != null)
        .Select(x => x.ContextTimestamp)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Kiksen's answer is the choice if you want to set "-" to `DisplayTimeStamp` when the `.FirstOrDefault()` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# >= version 6, use the `?` operator like that:

```cs
DisplayTimeStamp = PredictionTableList?
    .Where(x => x.ContextTimestamp != null)?
    .Select(x => x.ContextTimestamp)?
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If PredictionTableList is `null` DisplayTimeStamp will be `null`. No other code will be executed.

Comment: Right! Fixed thanks

Comment: No need for .NET >= 5: The null-propagating operator (`?.`) was introduced with C# 6.0 (VS 2015, .NET Framework 4.6).

Comment: Thanks for the check @Heinzi, cannot believe that null-propagating operator has been implemented in C# a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DisplayTimeStamp = PredictionTableList?.Where(x => x.ContextTimestamp != null) .Select(x => x.ContextTimestamp).FirstOrDefault() ?? "-";
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-